# Sending Email in C# does not work

Tags: c#, winforms, email, smtp

I am writing a windows form that can send messages in C#.

I had this working and sending messages at one point, but now my program just hangs when it comes time to send the message.

Here is the code to send the message:

```
private void sendEmail()
    {
        string host = "";
        int port = 0;

        host = checkFromAddress(ref port);

        try
        {
            // Create the email to send
            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
            message.To.Add(recipient1.Text);
            message.Subject = "subject";
            message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(userName.Text);
            message.Body = "Test Messge";

            // Setup smtp information related to the host used
            System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = host;
            smtp.Port = port;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName.Text, password.Text);

            // Send the message
            smtp.Send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please check email settings and try again");
        }
    }
```

The username and password are entered into the form, the host and port are determined based on the user's credentials.

I debug the program and when it gets to smtp.Send(message), it just hangs and I am unable to bring up the form. I have to stop debugging or kill the process.

Any ideas why it is not working?

Comment: Have you tried to let it timeout ?

Comment: I know that the constructor in MailAddress(userName.Text) requires the variable to be an email address rather than name? Other than that I suggest the approach of reducing the component parts. Set some string literals that you know for sure should work, then work backwards.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I will see what happens if I let it timeout.

Comment: My fault guys, it was a host port issue I was having. I visited multiple sites to get server info and one of them must have had the wrong port number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you verify that all the values getting passed in are valid?  Possible things to check are host/port.  Also, are the 'from' and 'to' getting valid email addresses?  Those look a little suspect.

Comment: I am checking those right now. I believe the addresses entered in might be the problem, the timeout resulted in an error message I put in there, so there is some setup problems